# Not able to access any tabs in AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm not able to access any tabs in AAD. What could be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below points can be worked around in your case.

- Buttions or options being greyed out  maybe because , you may not have had global admin rights/user administrator rights on the azure AD tenant. There are a few roles which can create users within the directory. You may not have any roles within the directory which permit the operations.
  Reference: [github issue.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/43420#issuecomment-557922107)
- Even in Azure AD free edition ,one should be able to create the users if you have proper roles .
- On completion of the first 30 days of Microsoft Azure’s free trial,
  your ‘Free Trial’ Azure Subscription will be disabled. To fix this,
  the subscription needs to be changed to the ‘Pay-As-You-Go’ plan
  instead of the ‘Free Trial’ plan which it is currently on.
- *For example* :For applications under Enterprise application,  one of the following roles: Global Administrator, Cloud Application
  Administrator, Application Administrator, or owner of the service
  principal.
- You can check [Azure AD built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#all-roles), and by checking the
  description of  role , assign the required one to manage identity .
- You can [Assign Azure AD roles to users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/manage-roles-portal) to manage the identities
  if you have global or role **administrator rights**. Approach the
  admin to  assign the roles .Also see  [custom roles in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-create) 
  if needed.
- Please check if this issue  [in - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/591297/why-i-can39t-add-authentication-method-on-user-on.html) can relate .

If issue still remains you can raise a [support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-troubleshooting-support-howto#:%7E:text=How%20to%20open%20a%20support%20ticket%20for%20Azure,a%20Summary%20for%20the%20request.%20...%20See%20More.) in troubleshoot+support blade.